# Error when trying to run login form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Here's my code...

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim con As SqlConnection

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        con = New SqlConnection("Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Vehicle;Trusted_Connection=True;")
        con.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [user] where userid= " + txtuser.Text + " AND password= " + txtpass.Text + "", con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            MsgBox("Succesfully loggedin")
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

when I try to run the programs, it shows this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid column name 'admin'.

Invalid column name 'admin'.

'admin' is on the value stored in the userid column under 'user' table under 'Vehicle' database..I'm creating a small Win application for our office but I was stacked with this one, this is also part of my practice.

thanks for the help guys..

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with a warning: use [SQLParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!

In this case the problem is that you pass a SELECT like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [user] where userid = admin
```

So SQL Server thinks admin is a column name.

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM [user] where userid = 'admin'
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape your text. This is what your DB sees:

```
SELECT * FROM [user] where userid= admin AND password= somepass
```

This is what you want it to see:

```
SELECT * FROM [user] where userid= 'admin' AND password = 'somepass'
```

To fix this, re-write your code like:

"SELECT * FROM [user] where userid= '" + txtuser.Text + "' AND password= '" + txtpass.Text + "'"

(note the single quotes).

You should also worry about what would happen if the userid or password included a single quote, you can fix this by doing `Replace(txtuser.Text,"'","''")`

Comment: those single quotes worked for me..thanks to everyone who answered who had actually had the same answers..I didn't even realize I need those..

Answer (score 0):

You need to encase the contents txtUser.Text and txtPass.Text in apostrophes, to escape them.  You're currently trying to match a column called admin.

For example;

```
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [user] where userid='" & txtuser.Text & "' AND password='" & txtpass.Text & "';", con)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

What you really should be doing is something like this;

```
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [user] WHERE userid=@U AND password=@P;", con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@U", SqlDBType.NVarChar).Value = txtUser.Text.Trim
cmd.Parameters.Add("@P", SqlDBType.NVarChar).Value = txtPass.Text.Trim
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

I find this simplifies things quite a bit.